# Infinite loop when looping through the values in a column

Tags: excel, vba

The below code works for 1 or 2 numeric values in column F on the RD1 sheet, however when there are more than 2 values the code that checks the F column loops infinitely, as well as the section that offsets the source and target cells I am struggling to understand how to end these infinite loops and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub UpdateCalibrationCert5()

    Dim RD1Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim CalibrationCertSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sourceCell As Range, sourceCell2 As Range, targetCell As Range, targetCell2 As Range, insertRange As Range, startCell As Range, startSourceCell As Range, startSourceCell2 As Range, startTargetCell As Range, startTargetCell2 As Range
    Dim descriptionRange As Range, descriptionDestRange As Range, itemNumberCell As Range, itemDestCell As Range, afaaCell As Range, afaaDestCell As Range, offsetCell As Range, offsetDestCell As Range, afaaOffsetCell As Range, afaaOffsetDestCell As Range
    Dim cell As Range, copyRange As Range
    Dim counter As Long, counter2 As Long, loopCount As Long, i As Long
    
    ' Set the worksheets
    Set RD1Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RD1")
    Set CalibrationCertSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Calibration Cert.")
    
    ' Initialize counter
    counter = -1
    counter2 = -1
    
    ' Start from F28 on the "RD1" sheet
    Dim setpointCell As Range
    Dim UUCCell As Range
    Set setpointCell = RD1Sheet.Range("F28")
    Set UUCCell = RD1Sheet.Range("F28")
    
    ' Loop through every 7th column until an empty cell is encountered
    Do While Not IsEmpty(UUCCell)
        ' Check if the current cell has a numerical value (excluding errors like #DIV/0!)
        If IsNumeric(UUCCell.Value) And Not IsError(UUCCell.Value) Then
            ' Increase the counter by 1
            counter2 = counter2 + 1
        End If
        
        ' Offset 7 columns from the current cell
        Set UUCCell = UUCCell.Offset(0, 7)
    Loop
    
    ' Set the range to insert for multiple UUC's on Cal cert (N1:AX53)
    Set insertRange = CalibrationCertSheet.Range("N1:AX53")
    
    'set start point for insert of calibration cert sheets
    Set startCell = CalibrationCertSheet.Range("N1")
    
    ' Loop through and insert the range to the right based on the counter value
    For i = 1 To counter2
        insertRange.Copy
        startCell.Offset(0, i * 37).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Next i
    
    'Adds make & model, description &item number to cert sheet
    Set UUCCell = RD1Sheet.Range("F28")
    Set afaaCell = RD1Sheet.Range("D19")
    Set afaaDestCell = CalibrationCertSheet.Range("S10")
    Set descriptionRange = RD1Sheet.Range("D13:D16")
    Set descriptionDestRange = CalibrationCertSheet.Range("U13:U16")
    Set itemNumberCell = RD1Sheet.Range("B19")
    Set itemDestCell = CalibrationCertSheet.Range("S13")
    Set offsetCell = RD1Sheet.Range("E18")
    Set offsetDestCell = CalibrationCertSheet.Range("AB22")
    Set afaaOffsetCell = RD1Sheet.Range("C18")
    Set afaaOffsetDestCell = CalibrationCertSheet.Range("S22")
    
    Do While Not IsEmpty(UUCCell)
        If IsNumeric(UUCCell.Value) And Not IsError(UUCCell.Value) Then
            ' Copy values from current cells to destination cells
            descriptionDestRange.Value = descriptionRange.Value
            itemDestCell.Value = itemNumberCell.Value
            afaaDestCell.Value = afaaCell.Value
            afaaOffsetDestCell.Value = afaaOffsetCell.Value
            offsetDestCell.Value = offsetCell.Value
    
            ' Offset destination cells
            Set afaaDestCell = afaaDestCell.Offset(0, 37)
            Set offsetDestCell = offsetDestCell.Offset(0, 37)
            Set afaaOffsetDestCell = afaaOffsetDestCell.Offset(0, 37)
            Set descriptionDestRange = descriptionDestRange.Offset(0, 37)
            Set itemDestCell = itemDestCell.Offset(0, 36)
        End If
    
        ' Offset to after adjustment
        Set UUCCell = UUCCell.Offset(0, 7)
        Set afaaCell = afaaCell.Offset(0, 4)
        Set offsetCell = offsetCell.Offset(0, 7)
        Set afaaOffsetCell = afaaOffsetCell.Offset(0, 7)
        Set descriptionRange = descriptionRange.Offset(0, 7)
        Set itemNumberCell = itemNumberCell.Offset(0, 7)
    
        ' Clear clipboard
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Loop

    ' Loop through cells in column F on "RD1" sheet
    Do While IsNumeric(setpointCell.Value)
        On Error Resume Next
        ' Increment counter
        counter = counter + 1
        ' Move down 12 rows
        Set setpointCell = setpointCell.Offset(12, 0)
        ' Check for errors
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    ' Set the initial copy range for increasing setpoint rows on cert sheet
    Set copyRange = CalibrationCertSheet.Range("S21:AR21")
    
    ' Loop through the range offset for counter2 (No of UUC's) times
    For i = 1 To counter2 + 1
        ' Copy the range
        copyRange.Copy
        
        ' Insert cells in "Calibration Cert." sheet based on the counter number
        copyRange.Resize(counter).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    
        ' Offset the copy range by 37 columns for the next iteration
        Set copyRange = copyRange.Offset(-counter, 37)
    Next i
    
    ' Set the initial cells for source and target
    Set startSourceCell = RD1Sheet.Range("F28")
    Set startSourceCell2 = RD1Sheet.Range("G26")
    Set startTargetCell = CalibrationCertSheet.Range("S21")
    Set startTargetCell2 = CalibrationCertSheet.Range("Y21")
    
    ' Outer loop to repeat the process across the spreadsheets
    For i = 1 To counter2 * 2
        ' Set the initial cells to the starting position for the current iteration
        Set sourceCell = startSourceCell
        Set sourceCell2 = startSourceCell2
        Set targetCell = startTargetCell
        Set targetCell2 = startTargetCell2
        
        ' Loop through each cell in the applied column
        Do While IsNumeric(sourceCell.Value) Or loopCount = 0
            ' If loopCount is 0 and the source cell value is not numeric, then skip this iteration
            If loopCount = 0 And Not IsNumeric(sourceCell.Value) Then
                Set startTargetCell = startTargetCell.Offset(0, -32)
                Set startTargetCell2 = startTargetCell2.Offset(0, -32)
                Exit Do
            End If
            
            ' Copy the value to the target sheet
            targetCell.Value = sourceCell.Value
            targetCell2.Value = sourceCell2.Value
            
            ' Move the source cell by 12 rows
            Set sourceCell = sourceCell.Offset(12, 0)
            Set sourceCell2 = sourceCell2.Offset(12, 0)
            
            ' Move the target cell by 1 row
            Set targetCell = targetCell.Offset(1, 0)
            Set targetCell2 = targetCell2.Offset(1, 0)
            
            ' Increment loop counter
            loopCount = loopCount + 1
        Loop
        
        ' Once the loop exits (when sourceCell no longer contains a numeric value)
        ' Offset the source and target cells for the next iteration
        Set startSourceCell = startSourceCell.Offset(0, 7)
        Set startSourceCell2 = startSourceCell2.Offset(0, 7)
        Set startTargetCell = startTargetCell.Offset(0, 32)
        Set startTargetCell2 = startTargetCell2.Offset(0, 32)
        
        ' Reset the loop count
        loopCount = 0
    Next i
    
    ' Display a message with the number of values copied
    MsgBox "Certificate complete!", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Do While IsNumeric(setpointCell.Value) and len(setpointCell.Value)>0`. If the cell is blank, `IsNumeric()` returns True. Why do you use `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: Seems like you might be able to reduce the amount of code down to the single loop which is giving you problems?

Comment: Thank you! That has fixed the problem for counting the F column, I am still fairly new to this and I tried to add some error handling but I don't think it does anything.

Comment: Definitely do not use `On Error Resume Next` unless it's *very* targeted/restricted: you should know what type of error you're ignoring (and that you can safely do so), and cancel it with `On Error Goto 0` as soon as that line/section of code is done.